# MVC - display a date without the time when the date could be nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date

I am using ASP.Net with MVC and trying to display dates without the time. I have two dates, a StartDate and EndDate. I am able to display the StartDate without the time however having trouble with the EndDate. From my reading, I believe it is due to it being a nullable date. My EndDate is defined as:

```
 public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; Set; }
```

While my display is:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
```

I was able to display my StartDate by defining a new string:

```
 public string ReturnStartDateForDisplay {
    get
    {
        return this.StartDate.ToString("d");
    }
 }
```

and displaying it with:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model.Item => item.ReturnStartDateForDisplay)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
public string ReturnEndDateForDisplay
{
    get
    {
        return this.EndDate.HasValue ? this.EndDate.Value.ToString("d"): string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model.Item => item.ReturnEndDateForDisplay)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to define a new `ReturnStartDateForDisplay` property. Use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and decorate your `StartDate` and `EndDate` with a `DisplayFormat` attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? EndDate{ get; set; }
```

Null values will be magically handled for you.

Comment: That worked much better. With the previous example I encountered an issue with my 'update'